# Communication between multiple users of one extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am planning on building an chrome extension that would allow 2+ users communication on different devices. Basically one user would fill out the textarea and send encrypted (if needed) message and the other user would receive it and decrypt.

I am wondering if there's an API that would allow for such communication. (I'm pretty sure neither broadcast channels or chrome.runtime.messages doesn't work in this scenario.).

Comment: you need a server to initiate a connection between the two browsers. Then use webRTC to send the messages between the two browsers.... OR you need to use a backend server which gets the message from one user and sends it to other

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.